# c# in timer tick want to count++ 0 to 30 and then count -- 30 to 0 again and again. how to do?

Tags: c#, winforms

```cs
namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        int A = 0;

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
            A++;
            if (A == 30)
            {
                A--;
            }
            textBox1.Text = A.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the type of thing where you need to take your time and note down everything you want to keep track of. How will the program know where to start counting? How will it know where to stop? How will it know the current value? How will it know which way to count? How will it know when to switch? Each of those things require an answer. Once you have those figured out, the solution becomes easier to figure out.

Answer (score 5):

Just store the direction you're going and flip it when you reach the limits:

```cs
int A = 0;
int direction = 1;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    A += direction;

    if (A == 30 || A == 0)
    {
        direction = -direction;
    }
    textBox1.Text = A.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Make sure you don't start out with a value outside the bounds.

Comment: @Fildor Yep, or the `if` statement could be `if(A <= 0 || A >= 30)` and clamp A to the bounds :)